# jQuery unable to parse JSON

Tags: json, jquery

I am doing a simple get using jquery like so

```
var jqxhr = $.get("http://localhost/path/list", function() {
        alert("success");
    }, "json")
    .done(function() { alert("second success"); })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.dir(jqXHR);
    }
);
```

The server return the following JSON with status 200. I am able to parse it as a valid json like I am able to do here: http://www.freeformatter.com/json-formatter.html. But always the fail method is called. If I change the dataType as "text", the success method is called. So I assume that jquery is not able to parse the response as a valid json. What could be wrong?

```
{
    'root': {
        'status': [
            {
                'Entity': 'user',
                'InstanceId': '1',
                'ModifiedAt': 'null',
                'ModifiedBy': 'null',
                'CreatedAt': 'null',
                'CreatedBy': '1',
                'Status': 'approval',
                'AssignedFor': 'null',
                'AssignedTo': '1',
                'PatternName': 'approval'
            },
            {
                'Entity': 'user',
                'InstanceId': '2',
                'ModifiedAt': 'null',
                'ModifiedBy': 'null',
                'CreatedAt': 'null',
                'CreatedBy': '1',
                'Status': 'start',
                'AssignedFor': 'null',
                'AssignedTo': '1',
                'PatternName': 'input'
            }
        ],
        'count': 2
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not valid JSON. Strings and keys must be in **double** quotes. Try http://jsonlint.org/. The information on the page you linked to, that JavaScript would tolerate single quotes, is incorrect (maybe they confuse object literals with JSON, who knows).

Comment: Invalid JSON . check json http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: dughh! Did not realize that working late night! I should remember to use http://jsonlint.org/. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

By what way did you serialized JSON? And convert single quotes to double quotes

```
{
"root": {
    "status": [
        {
            "Entity": "user",
            "InstanceId": "1",
            "ModifiedAt": "null",
            "ModifiedBy": "null",
            "CreatedAt": "null",
            "CreatedBy": "1",
            "Status": "approval",
            "AssignedFor": "null",
            "AssignedTo": "1",
            "PatternName": "approval"
        },
        {
            "Entity": "user",
            "InstanceId": "2",
            "ModifiedAt": "null",
            "ModifiedBy": "null",
            "CreatedAt": "null",
            "CreatedBy": "1",
            "Status": "start",
            "AssignedFor": "null",
            "AssignedTo": "1",
            "PatternName": "input"
        }
    ],
    "count": "2"
}}
```